# how to make the same image size for 3x3 subplots

Tags: subfloats

[image]In the code below,I produced each image separately in matlab and saved it as .eps.Then ,I used this code to put all nine images together as 3x3. However, their sizes looked different in height and width!. How can I fix such a problem.I can not manipulate .eps images in powerpoint !!!.Also, I wanted this set of subplots to fill the whole page but it did fill only half of the page, I really like them to look bigger.Any help is appreciated.
thanks in advance.

```
 \begin{figure}
        \centering
        \subfloat\[\]\[\emph{caption pic. 1}.\]
        {\includegraphics\[width=.3\textwidth\]{10t10w125x300y}} \quad
        \subfloat\[\]\[\emph{caption pic. 2}.\]
        {\includegraphics\[width=.3\textwidth\]{10t40w250x400y}} \quad
        \subfloat\[\]\[\emph{caption pic. 3}.\]
        {\includegraphics\[width=.3\textwidth\]{10t100w340x500y}} \\
        \subfloat\[\]\[\emph{caption pic. 4}.\]
        {\includegraphics\[width=.3\textwidth\]{30t10w200x400y}} \quad
        \subfloat\[\]\[\emph{caption pic. 5}.\]
        {\includegraphics\[width=.3\textwidth\]{30t40w350x750y}} \quad
        \subfloat\[\]\[\emph{caption pic. 6}.\]
        {\includegraphics\[width=.3\textwidth\]{30t100w550x1200y}} \\
        \subfloat\[\]\[\emph{caption pic. 7}.\]
        {\includegraphics\[width=.3\textwidth\]{50t10w300x600y}} \quad
        \subfloat\[\]\[\emph{caption pic. 8}.\]
        {\includegraphics\[width=.3\textwidth\]{50t40w600x1100y}} \quad
        \subfloat\[\]\[\emph{caption pic. 9}.\]
        {\includegraphics\[width=.3\textwidth\]{50t100w600x1500y}}
        \caption{Insert caption.}
        \label{fig:subfig}
        \end{figure}][1]
```

Comment: If you put the images in separate figures, are they still different heights and widths? Or if you look for a `BoundingBox` line in the EPS file itself? They probably are different. If you're doing any manual adjustment of figure windows in MATLAB, you'll have a hard time getting consistent figures. You might need something like [setting the `PaperPosition` and `PaperPositionMode` properties](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/figure-properties.html) to make your figures consistent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Measure the height of one of the images and use that on the rest.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subfig}

\newlength{\common}

\begin{document}
\noindent\rule{\textwidth}{1pt}
\begin{figure}[htp]
\settoheight{\common}{\includegraphics[width=.3\textwidth]{example-image}}% get height
\subfloat[picture 1]{\includegraphics[width=.3\textwidth,height=\common]{example-image}}\hfill
\subfloat[picture 2]{\includegraphics[width=.3\textwidth,height=\common]{euclid-1.jpg}}\hfill
\subfloat[picture 3]{\includegraphics[width=.3\textwidth,height=\common]{images/supper.png}}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

For the image size you read a comment of mike Renfro. If Matlab doesn't generate equal size of image, you can only resize them by

```
\includegraphics[width=0.32\hize,height=0.32\hsize]{your image}
```

but his will change the original aspect ratio of images, consequently they can became very ugly. If your paper size is A$, than its height is 1,441 times bigger then width. If your images has equal aspect ratio, than they will better fill a page as if thy have square shape.

One way to overcome this is locally enlarge text width. For example with help of changepage package. just add in preamble

```
\usepackage[strict]{changepage}
```

and put your image content in

```
\begin{adjustwidth*}{}{-<some size>}
... figure content ....
\end{adjustwidth}
```

For details read the package documentation.

The code, which you provide in your question, I doubt that it work. so I construct a new MWE, with which you can experiment further

```
\documentclass{article}
    \usepackage{graphicx}
    \usepackage[labelsep=space,
                labelfont={sf,bf},
                textfont=sf]{subfig}
 \begin{document}
    \begin{figure*}
\subfloat[picture 1 \label{fig:picture 1}]
        {\includegraphics[width=0.32\textwidth]{example-image}}
    \hfill
\subfloat[picture 2 \label{fig:picture 2}]
        {\includegraphics[width=0.32\textwidth]{example-image}}
    \hfill
\subfloat[picture 3 \label{fig:picture 3}]
        {\includegraphics[width=0.32\textwidth]{example-image}}
    \vskip\baselineskip
\subfloat[picture 4 \label{fig:picture 4}]
        {\includegraphics[width=0.32\textwidth]{example-image}}
    \hfill
\subfloat[picture 5 \label{fig:picture 5}]
        {\includegraphics[width=0.32\textwidth]{example-image}}
    \hfill
\subfloat[picture 6 \label{fig:picture 6}]
        {\includegraphics[width=0.32\textwidth]{example-image}}
    \vskip\baselineskip
\subfloat[picture 7 \label{fig:picture 7}]
        {\includegraphics[width=0.32\textwidth]{example-image}}
    \hfill
\subfloat[picture 8 \label{fig:picture 8}]
        {\includegraphics[width=0.32\textwidth]{example-image}}
    \hfill
\subfloat[picture 9 \label{fig:picture 9}]
        {\includegraphics[width=0.32\textwidth]{example-image}}
\caption{Insert caption}
    \label{fig:mean and std of nets}
    \end{figure*}
\end{document}
```

Well, this is probably is not real answer, but I hope, that can direct you to it.